# CSS, is it possible to create this corner effect

Tags: css

My CSS ability is very limited. I'm wondering if there's a way to create this type of effect:

http://www.wendyfawcettlaw.com/sample.html

Here's the live site, I already have the drop shadow. I just need to get those two red corner elements in.

Thanks in advance for any help!!

Comment: oops, here's the live site with the drop shadow box: http://www.wendyfawcettlaw.com/

Comment: FYI - the text on the live site with the huge drop shadows (ie 8) is very hard to read. You might consider toning that down quite a bit.  FF 4 on the other hand looks pretty good.

Answer (score 5):

Here we go: http://jsfiddle.net/JeaffreyGilbert/9q4Up/

Cheers.

Comment: You should probably place them behind, otherwise I can't select the text in the corners.

Comment: It should be noted that IE8 and below don't support the box-shadow property (that is, the shadow won't appear), so be sure to evaluate your site's intended audience and set up an appropriate fallback for those browsers if necessary.

Comment: @alex Thanks. @Denise You can move redcorner div's above the paragraph to be able to select text in the corners.

@peterjmag Thanks for your note. @Denise peterjmag is correct, you should probably create a fallback if you want the shadow appears in IE.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it would be possible in pure CSS, you would probably need some additional HTML.
My recommendation would be to use some absolute positioned DIV with the red corners.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with 1 single image which is then tiled with border-image using only one element. Very clean minimalist mark-up and CSS.   If you are interested in this solution, I can post an explanation on how it works because its quite tricky to understand at first but once you get it you can make some pretty cool borders.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather suggest to use as image, because you can later change whatever style you want to do, and have fun in inserting interesting variation of design, for your website.

@Jeaffrey Gilbert has already give you the solution in simple html+css code, I will give you mine about CSS3 using multiple backgrounds.

And you do not need to adding HTML (but it will work only or every decent browser and not for Internet Explorer)

```
background: 
    url(image_1.gif) top left no-repeat,
    url(image_2.gif) bottom right no-repeat;
```

Comment: Thanks, this alternative is useful. @Denise You better add this way if you don't consider IE8 (need fallback as well).